# Floating blocs bug with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find a solution to my problem with float blocs with Bootstrap.
I think pictures are better than useless explanaitions so here is my problem :

As you can see below, all the divs are well placed with the `.img-responsive` bootstrap class on the pictures. But in this example, i gave a fixed height value to the 3rd picture.

[image]

All the pictures have a different height, and I though the `.img-responsive` class will fit all the divs automatically.
Here is the problem that i'm encountering now, when i let the `height:auto;` (I hovered the 2nd div to show you the padding and margin applied to the divs :

[image]

All the divs are not well placed, and it looks very ugly...

I would that all divs can fit automatically, even if the height is different (it could gave a better effect!).

Have you guys an idea to solve my problem ? Because i tried a lot of things, and nothing works well except to give to the imgs a fix height value.. But it's not very interesting for the responsive view...

Have a good day!

Comment: try to use box-sizing:border-box in image block and use nth-child(3n){clear:both}

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well with the nth-child solution, but with (4n) ! ;) Thanks again!

Comment: your welcome RoyLaPoutre !